# Bootstrap inline form width of inputs

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have a row that has **two input boxes**, `Name` and `Email` side by side. Below that will be a textarea for a message. I want the two input boxes to take up 6 of the columns in the grid system as well as the textarea.

Using **form-inline** I can't figure out how to get the widths of the **two input boxes** to extend the full width of the column. Any ideas?

http://www.bootply.com/yL5atrBZfX

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-inline col-md-6 col-centered">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-centered form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" style="resize: none" cols="5" rows="10" placeholder="Message" id="MessageBox"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you wrap the name/email inputs inside of another row with each having col-md-6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the inner `Name` and `Email` inputs inside of another row with two columns which take the full width of the row:

http://www.bootply.com/WOvj1ygeAx

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-centered">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email Address">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-centered form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" style="resize: none" cols="5" rows="10" placeholder="Message" id="MessageBox"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Also just a note, `form-inline` does not belong on a `col-*` element like the example you provided. It should be used on the `<form>` element.  Based on the example you provided it seems redundant here. See: [Bootstrap CSS - Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to make the space between the two input boxes, consistent with the space between the large text area?

Comment: You can use `form-group` instead of `row`.  It's basically a special row that has additional spacing